# 18.04: color emoji not showing up at all in Chrome, only partially in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, 18.04, emoji

I've upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 and was hoping to have better emoji support. The results are that Chrome (66) is still using the old black and white emoji font, and Firefox (59) is managing to show *some* color emoji but not others. I took some advice to install the font EmojiOne but that didn't seem to help

Screenshots from the emoji demo page at http://eosrei.github.io/emojione-color-font/full-demo.html :

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04+ you can now simply install a single package: `fonts-noto-color-emoji`. After that, restart Chrome and it will take effect. No need for creating a manual font configuration.

<sup>This package is supposed to be installed on the regular Ubuntu 18.04+ desktop flavor (on a 'Recommended' level of dependency - check for yourself with `apt rdepends fonts-noto-color-emoji`). Some other flavors like Kubuntu (KDE) don't have this by default and require you to install it manually.</sup>

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Chrome v71 from Google's official repository. The other answer did do the trick.

Comment: @undercatapplaudsMonica there are multiple other answers now.

Comment: Which other answer?

Answer (score 83):

For anyone else having the problem, uninstalling and re-installing the font pack worked for me (Ubuntu 19.10)

```
$ sudo apt remove fonts-noto-color-emoji
$ sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

or just

```
$ sudo apt reinstall fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

Then restart Chrome.

**Edit:**

The problems comesback *sometimes* when Chrome gets an update, and then I have to re-install the font.

IDK if it helps but maybe copying the font into `/usr/local/share/fonts` will solve this for future updates:

```
sudo cp -r /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto /usr/local/share/fonts/truetype/noto
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for 19.04

Comment: same here, did the trick

Comment: thx guy! have to do this another time after a while. Don't know why this font package get "corrupted"...

Comment: This solution does not work after Restart.

Comment: @AksharPatel it has been working for me. Perhaps try to reinstall Chrome altogether and reinstalling the font packs afterwards would help.

Comment: when you restart the problem comes back again :(

Comment: Well, it worked for me. Now, it'd be rather interesting to know *why*...

Comment: The same can be achieved with a single command:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-noto-color-emoji`

Whatever method any of you use, It is required to restart your browsers after reinstall of fonts package. Firefox and Chrome Emojis are back!

Comment: This only temporarily fixes the problem. I just reinstalled it again yesterday, and today emoji were broken again in both Chrome and Brave.

Comment: @Matthias Happened to me as well. Unsure why I had to reinstall again. I can't really remember if I did updates that could have changed anything.

Comment: Related bug report: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-noto-color-emoji/+bug/1859926

Comment: Reinstall and restart Chrome worked on an out-of-the-box 20.04 install. Bizarre, but it works!

Comment: Worked at Debian 5.10.140-1, 2022. thanks, brilliant answer.

Answer (score 55):

I fixed it - I had to follow [these instructions](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/enable-color-emoji-linux-google-chrome-noto) from 2016  I had to create `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/01-emoji.conf` with the following text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

The bit in the original instructions about installing Noto font was unnecessary since it's installed as part of 18.04 by default.

Then run:

```
fc-cache -f -v
```

On the next restart, Chrome has color emoji.

Comment: -1, because of two reasons: 1) the local fontconfig isn't required any longer in 18.04. 2) *"installing Noto font was unnecessary since it's installed as part of 18.04 by default"* isn't universally true. I have a full KDE desktop installation and it wasn't installed at all.  See also [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1059396/88802).

Comment: Do you know if that's all true for upgradees too? I sensed that my problems might have had to do with being a 17.10 upgrade.

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and after installing The Noto Fonts I still had the same problem. However, this did the trick for me. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it was the config file or simply the call to "fc-cache" which caused the change. Maybe both were needed.

Comment: This fixed emoji in Chrome but unfortunately broke them in [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/).  Ultimately I had to revert it altogether to avoid the side effects.

Comment: This did not have any effect on Pop_OS 19.10.

Comment: I need both installing font and fontconfig to fix in Xfce, not only in Chrome, but also in Brave and Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use that demo page to test color emoji. That page only demonstrates the EmojiOne font which isn't installed by default in Ubuntu (although Firefox uses a variation of it).

Instead use https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Look at the Browser column. In default Ubuntu, it should mostly match the Google column. (Except for the Browser column, all the other columns are just `.png` icons). When I tested today, the Google column is just a bit out of date as Google has made some changes to some of their emoji that haven't been incorporated into the website. (For instance, the hamburger has cheese on top of the burger.)

Comment: Fair enough, but this is not an answer to the original question - how to enable color emojis in Chrome.

Comment: @gertvdijk Color emoji _does_ work in Google Chrome. What specific web site is causing you a problem?

Comment: Ok, I see that you fixed your issue by installing fonts-noto-color-emoji. I tried to get every Ubuntu 18.04 LTS flavor to include that package by default, but the Lubuntu and Kubuntu developers didn't want it.

Comment: @Jeremy_Bicha Yeah, on Kubuntu. But, my point was, your 'answer' is more of a comment to the other answer about the test page to use. It doesn't really *answer* the Q/OP.

Comment: Your link is misleading because it has a font-family CSS rule for the "Browser" column that includes specific fonts like "Noto Color Emoji". The majority of websites are **not** going to have that CSS rule. So for me emoji renders fine on your link with the `fonts-noto-color-emoji` package installed, until I disable that CSS rule then they don't. If I copy+paste some emoji from your link to gedit or a terminal window, some render fine and some don't (e.g. U+2603 ☃ doesn't work while U+26C4 ⛄ does).

Comment: @AbeVoelker Exactly, my problem is emojis renders well when the font family is specified. If not, only partially are rendered and my rendered set is different than OP's screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

I use [emoji.conf](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/emoji.conf).

[image]

...............

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me on 20.04. the installer didn't work though. i had to manually copy both files in /root/etc/fonts to my own /etc/fonts/. upon restarting chrome i finally had emojis. thanks!

Comment: Oh, what happens when you run the installer?

Comment: very weird. i just ran your installer again to send you the error and it worked fine ‍♀️

Comment: Link updated, so now it works with any emoji font.

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella
Any more details on how to use this tool? Or do i just have to install it and I'm done?

Comment: @LetsFailNoob Guess why these files names: "install-uninstall.sh", "_font.txt" 

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella I mean yeah should be pretty clear, but since nothing changed after installing I was wondering whether or not I did something wrong.

Comment: @LetsFailNoob You also need to install the emoji font.

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella A Build-newby-question: What are the steps to run this tool?

Comment: @Filbuntu If your distro exhibit problems with emoji, you are better asking them to include this tool in their packages. The package maintainer will know what to do.

Comment: Thanks bro for the information this really worked for me as i wanted just downloaded the project and run the install-uninstall.sh and the problem get solved

Comment: Great 

Answer (score 3):

It seems this problem can be caused by having multiple incompatible emoji fonts installed, and/or having wrong default font selected in Chrome.

1. Make sure you have `fonts-noto-color-emoji` package installed.

   ```
   sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji
   ```
2. Create/Edit font config files as in [@N3dst4's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029675/384898).

   - Note: While @N3dst4 put his config file in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/01-emoji.conf`, I put my in `~/.config/font-manager/local.conf` because of how my system is set up.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
   <fontconfig>
     <alias>
       <family>serif</family>
       <prefer>
         <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
       </prefer>
     </alias>
     <alias>
       <family>sans-serif</family>
       <prefer>
         <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
       </prefer>
     </alias>
     <alias>
       <family>monospace</family>
       <prefer>
         <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
       </prefer>
     </alias>
   </fontconfig>
   ```
3. Set default fonts in Chrome to variations of "Noto".
4. Rebuild font cache + restart chrome.

   ```
   fc-cache -f -v
   ```
5. If emojis are still not displayed correctly see what fonts are used to render them with `right click on emoji -> Inspect -> Computed -> Rendered Fonts` and uninstall them.

   - Example: My emojis were rendered by font `Twitter Color Emoji`, so I needed to uninstall package `fonts-twemoji-svginot`.
   - You might not need to uninstall fonts if you play more with font config files, but I have not tested that.
   - Don't forget to rebuild font cache + restart chrome after uninstalling fonts.

BTW this also fixed [Zalgo text](http://www.eeemo.net/) for me.

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggestions here solved my problem that Google Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04 would not show color emoji, no matter what I did . Eventually I resolved my issue by running the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge fonts-symbola ttf-ancient-fonts-symbola
```

After this I restarted Google Chrome and color emojis finally worked .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is because multiple fonts provide the emoji. I have to remove `fonts-emojione` to make `fonts-noto-color-emoji` work.

Another potential font package may cause the conflict is `font-noto`.

[Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-noto-color-emoji/+bug/1859926/comments/8) to the related bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved by adding** [Emojis - Emoji Keyboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/emojis-emoji-keyboard/gaoflciahikhligngeccdecgfjngejlh) **extension to Chrome.**

Additionally, I checked that the [Chromoji - Emojis for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromoji-emojis-for-googl/negakbijaemdgbhklopmghphgaeadmpo?hl=en-US) extension also works.

**1st Note:** Emojis appear everywhere on the page except for inputs and textarea.

**2nd Note:** Any of these extensions additionally give us the ability to search for emojis along with the possibility of copying them.