# Ubuntu 19.10 emoji missing on google chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have ubuntu 19.10 on my computer and I installed google-chrome as default browser. I noticed that chrome not display emoji on different sites.  I tried reinstall, remove all catalog google-chrome from .config directory. Nothing from these actions didn't help. I also noticed that on firefox this problem not existing. Below I put images which describe the problem.
[image]

[image]

Comment: second image comes from firefox

Comment: I have also similar problem in for example onedrive. Checkbox icon not display properly on chrome and firefox.

Comment: Ok. I solved.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029661/18-04-color-emoji-not-showing-up-at-all-in-chrome-only-partially-in-firefox

Comment: Yes. But I'm wondering why I have to use it this solution. On my another machine this problem does not exist.

Comment: I was noticed that this problem began occur on my another machine.What's happening. Chrome's inspector do not respect system theme. Shortcuts in chrome have white background. Earlier it was dark background. I don't know is cause by chrome update or ubuntu update. Maybe somebody have similiar problem?